# Is it possible to create many QProgressDialogs objects, that will show progress different long operations?

Tags: c++, qt, qlist, qprogressbar

I have class, that launches tasks in separate thread:

```
class SomeTask : public QObject, QRunnable
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void updateProgressBar(int, int);
public:
    SomeTask(int, QWidget*);
    void run();
    void runLongOperation(QString)
    {
        QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(this);
    }
};
```

And in MainWindow I create for every long calculation new QProgressBar

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
private:
    QList<QProgressDialog*> m_listProgressDialogs;
public slots:
    void handle(QString) 
    {
          m_listProgressDialogs.push_back(new QProgressDialog("Task in progress...", "Cancel", 0, 100));
   m_listProgressDialogs.at(m_listProgressDialogs.size()-1)->show();

   SomeTask *task = new SomeTask(m_listProgressDialogs.size()-1, this);
   QObject::connect(mv, SIGNAL(updateProgressBar(int)), this, SLOT(setValueProgressBar(int)));
   task->runLongOperation(......);
    }
    void setValueProgressBar(int);
};
```

Is it possible to create new QProgressBar for every long task and every task will emit the signal to set value in specific QProgressBar. Is it good to store QProgressBar* in QList, like I wrote ?

Comment: "Is it possible to create many QProgressDialogs objects, that will show progress different long operations?" - Yes.

Comment: Or better use QProgressBar and combine them in some container (maybe with vertical scroll).

Comment: Having many popups is not very nice for the user, especially if you don't see them all, you should go for the idea of AlexanderVX or combine the total progress in a unique QProgressDialog.

Comment: *own progress dialog*